# Как сделать так, чтобы выводилось всё время от 0:00 и до заданного времени?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m, s;
    char d;
    vector<int>vm;
    vector<int>vs;
    cout << "Enter full time\n";
    cin >> m >> d >> s;
    if (s < 0 || s > 59)
        cout << "ERROR";
    for (int i = 0; i <= m;++i)
    {

        vm.push_back(i);
        if (i == m)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l <= s; ++l)
            {
                vs.push_back(l);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int l = 0; l <= 59; ++l)
            {
                vs.push_back(l);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < vm.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l < vs.size(); l++)
        {
            if(vs[l] < 10 && vs[l] >= 0)
                cout << vm[i] << ":0" << vs[l] << ' ';
            else
                cout << vm[i] << ':' << vs[l] <<' ';
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я один не понял, что нужно автору вопроса?...

Comment: Например, я ввожу 0:05 и вывести должно 0:00 0:01 0:02 0:03 0:04 0:05

Comment: @Harry, составлю компанию...

Comment: ну а если вводить 59 : 59, то должны выводится  3599 данных?...

Comment: ну получается что так

Comment: думаю вы не пытаетесь разобраться  в том, что пишете. Для начала лучше удалить полностью все, что вы написали и попытаться написать что то разумное

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m, s;
    char d;
    cout << "Enter full time\n";
    cin >> m >> d >> s;
    if (s < 0 || s > 59)
        cout << "ERROR";

    m = m*60+s;
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; ++i)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << i/60 << ':'
             << setw(2) << setfill('0') << i%60 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А как вы думаете,  что лучше:  один вложенный цикл или перевод всего времени в секунды, а потом каждый раз считать деление и процент?...

Comment: спасибо...........